# Foreman + NodeJS + MongoSkin: How to connect to mongodb from mongo cli?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, foreman, mongoskin

I have a simple helloworld project using foreman + nodejs + mongoskin.
It's acquire some data from an http get request and put it into mongodb via mongoskin.
The app works but I'm not able to connect to the db with the mongo cli.
When I start it with the same connection url used by mongoskin I have an exception: connect failed.

Comment: when you do a $ mongo in terminal what do you see ?

Comment: 1 - foreman start (the web app is up, with mongodb pointing to mongodb://localhost/gpswebtracking)
2 - from another console with mongo localhost/gpswebtracking I have:

MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4
connecting to: localhost/gpswebtracking
Sat Jun  9 13:28:45 Error: couldn't connect to server localhost shell/mongo.js:86
exception: connect failed

Comment: Is mongod running? What does "ps auwx | grep mongo" result in? [I'm presuming you're running Linux]